# Calculating the inverse Laplace transform of $F_{5}(s)=\frac{-A_{10} e^{-A_{7} \sqrt s }}{(\sqrt s+A_8) \sqrt{S+\theta_c}(S-A_4)}$ by residue theorem

Tags: solution-verification, laplace-transform, residue-calculus

I have calculated the ILT by residue theorem, but the result is wrong.
Would you like to check the calculation.
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Please type the question with mathjax. I've done the function for you, in the title but IMO it is too messy to expect someone to read this. Making it neater will make it more likely someone will try to help you.  You can have a look here for an introduction; its like LaTeX: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

$$Res(F_{5}(s),A_{4})=-\frac{A_{10}\ \  e^{-A_{7} \sqrt{A_{4}}\ +A_4\ t}}{\sqrt{A_{5}}(\sqrt{A_4}+A_8)},$$
$$\gamma_3: -R \rightarrow -\theta_c,\ s=r e^{i\pi},\ s+\theta_c=r e^{i\pi}+\theta_c;\quad \gamma_5: -\theta_c \rightarrow 0,\ s=r e^{i\pi},\ s+\theta_c=r e^{i\pi}+\theta_c; \quad \gamma_7: 0 \rightarrow -\theta_c, \ s=r e^{-i\pi},\ s+\theta_c=r e^{-i\pi}+\theta_c;\quad \gamma_9: -\theta_c \rightarrow -R,\ s=r e^{-i\pi},\ s+\theta_c=(r e^{i\pi}+\theta_c)e^{-2i\pi}.$$
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_3} F_{5}(s) e^{st}ds = -\frac{A_{10}}{2\pi i}\int_{R}^{\theta_c}\frac{e^{-A_7\sqrt{r}\ e^{i\pi/2}}\ e^{r e^{i\pi t}} e^{i\pi}dr}{(\sqrt{r }e^{i\pi /2}+A_8)\sqrt{r e^{i\pi}+\theta_c}(r e^{i\pi}-A_4)}=-\frac{A_{10}}{2\pi }\int^{R}_{\theta_c}\frac{e^{-iA_7\sqrt{r}}e^{-rt}dr}{(i\sqrt{r}+A_8)\sqrt{r-\theta_c}(r+A_4)},$$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_9} F_{5}(s) e^{st}ds = -\frac{A_{10}}{2\pi i}\int^{R}_{\theta_c}\frac{e^{-A_7\sqrt{r}\ e^{-i\pi/2}}\ e^{r e^{-i\pi t}} e^{-i\pi}dr}{(\sqrt{r }e^{-i\pi /2}+A_8)\sqrt{(r e^{i\pi}+\theta_c)e^{-2i\pi}}(r e^{-i\pi}-A_4)}=-\frac{A_{10}}{2\pi }\int^{R}_{\theta_c}\frac{e^{iA_7\sqrt{r}}e^{-rt}dr}{(-i\sqrt{r}+A_8)\sqrt{r-\theta_c}(r+A_4)},$$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_5} F_{5}(s) e^{st}ds = -\frac{A_{10}}{2\pi i}\int^{0}_{\theta_c}\frac{e^{-A_7\sqrt{r}e^{i\pi/2}}\ e^{r e^{i\pi t}}\ e^{i\pi}dr}{(\sqrt{r }e^{i\pi /2}+A_8)\sqrt{r e^{i\pi}+\theta_c}(r e^{i\pi}-A_4)}=\frac{A_{10}}{2\pi i}\int_{0}^{\theta_c}\frac{e^{-iA_7\sqrt{r}}e^{-rt}dr}{(i\sqrt{r}+A_8)\sqrt{\theta_c-r}(r+A_4)},$$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_7} F_{7}(s) e^{st}ds = -\frac{A_{10}}{2\pi i}\int_{0}^{\theta_c}\frac{e^{-A_7\sqrt{r}\ e^{-i\pi/2}}\ e^{r e^{-i\pi t}} e^{-i\pi}dr}{(\sqrt{r}e^{-i\pi /2}+A_8)\sqrt{r e^{i\pi}+\theta_c}(r e^{-i\pi}-A_4)}=-\frac{A_{10}}{2\pi i}\int_{0}^{\theta_c}\frac{e^{i A_7\sqrt{r}}e^{-rt}dr}{(-i\sqrt{r}+A_8)\sqrt{\theta_c-r}(r+A_4)},$$

$$ILT(F_{5}(s))=-\frac{A_{10}\ \  e^{-A_{7} \sqrt{A_{4}}\ +A_4\ t}}{\sqrt{A_{5}}(\sqrt{A_4}+A_8)} + \frac{A_{10}}{\pi }\int^{R}_{\theta_c}\frac{(A_8 \cos{A_7\sqrt r}-\sqrt r\sin{A_7\sqrt r})e^{-rt}dr}{(r+A_8^2)\sqrt{r-\theta_c}(r+A_4)} + \frac{A_{10}}{\pi }\int_{0}^{\theta_c}\frac{(A_8 \sin{A_7\sqrt r}+\sqrt r\cos{A_7\sqrt r})e^{-rt}dr}{(\sqrt{r}+A_8^2)\sqrt{\theta_c-r}(r+A_4)}.$$

I am not sure of the choice of paths and their parametric expressions.